# Linux - Generate random password based on requirements

Tags: linux, bash, password-generator

\Hello,
I've been searching for a day but cannot find a way to specify concrete password requirements when generating one with Bash:
-at least 12 char length:
-at least 4 different letters:
-at least 3 digits:
-at least 3 special chars -_+=#^*

I use the urandom: `tr -dc A-Za-z0-9_ < /dev/urandom | head -c 16 | xargs` which generates, in this case, 16 char string with letters, numbers and underscore. But I cannot specify the critera above.

Comment: At least show an example output? Also what have you tried where did it failed?

Comment: That's the thing. I cannot find such a thing where you can specify all these. Otherwise I use the urandom: `tr -dc A-Za-z0-9_ < /dev/urandom | head -c 16 | xargs` which generates, in this case, 16 char string with letters, numbers and underscore

Comment: Such rules are intended to make _users_ choose strong passwords. When using a _generated_ password, however, it's both simpler and more secure to just generate a random string of some fixed length, each character chosen uniformly from some set of characters; essentially what you have already. Adding more restrictions only makes the set of possible password smaller, thus brute force more feasible!

Comment: You could have your generator use the same protocol that humans use.  ie, output "abc123_-&" to satisfy the  (asinine) criteria and then append a string of 16 or 20 characters chosen from a uniformly random distribution.   As long as the random portion of the string is sufficiently long, you will not be weakening your password by conforming to the criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example this would fulfill criteria:

```
echo $(tr -dc A-Za-z < /dev/urandom | head -c 16)abcd123+-=
```

First criterium is easy and you already achieved that, others are fulfilled by fixed suffix appended to end.

You can make it bit better by random permutation of the result:

```
echo $(echo $(tr -dc A-Za-z < /dev/urandom | head -c 16)abcd123+-= | fold -w 1 | shuf | tr -d "\n")
```

(I helped myself with [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/158959/how-to-shuffle-characters-of-strings-in-bash))

Comment: Thank you and thank you for the link. Both gave me the idea to put my criteria in separate urandoms and then concatenate them `export LC_CTYPE=C
letters=$(tr -dc 'a-zA-Z' </dev/urandom | head -c 6)
digits=$(tr -dc '0-9' </dev/urandom | head -c 3)
special=$(tr -dc '#^*_.,+=-' </dev/urandom | head -c 3)
concat=${letters}${digits}${special}
pass=$(echo ${concat} | fold -w 1 | shuf | tr -d "\n")`
This way I have random everything. The only risk is from 6 letters I don't get 4 distinct ones, but such is life.

Comment: you can just append "abcd" and have it.

Comment: Yes, but the letters won't be 'random'. Just randomly placed in the resulting pass string.

Comment: That is right, but password is not worse, it in addition is guaranteed to fulfill criteria and you can add it before permuting all letters, so it would do increase the strength of the password.

Answer (score 0):

Solution in [TXR Lisp](https://www.nongnu.org/txr):

```
$ txr pwgen.tl
ix8K+6I6^#hp
$ txr pwgen.tl
s#J_&Eo348wl
$ txr pwgen.tl
dKt7V4#g&c9+
```

Code:

```
(let* ((abc (join "a".."z"))
       (ABC (upcase-str abc))
       (dig (join "0".."9"))
       (chr "-_+=#^&"))
  (labels ((relem (str) [str (rand (len str))])
           (dr (str n) [(shuffle str) 0..n])
           (r (str n) (str-seq (take n (gun (relem str))))))
    (flow `@(dr abc 4)@(r dig 3)@(r chr 3)@(r ABC 2)`
      shuffle
      put-line)))
```

We must call `(make-random-state)` to make a new, randomized state for the pseudo-random-number generator (PRNG), and store that in `*random-state*`. Otherwise we will get the same password every time.

The rules about which chararacters must be present give us ten characters. So we need two more. Let us meet that requirement by choosing two random upper case letters.

The program prepares some strings: `abc` contains the alphabet, `dig` the digits `0` through `9` and so on.

There are some local functions: `(relem str)` chooses a random character from the string `str`; `(dr str n)` chooses `n` different random ("dr") characters from `str` and returns them as a string; `(r str n)` chooses `n` random characters from `str`, not necessarily different.

We then use these functions inside a quasistring: a back-quoted string template with interpolation. That gives us a string in which the required items are in order: four different letters, three digits, three characters from the set, and then two random upper case letters.

We inject this string into a pipeline using `flow` which passes it thorugh `shuffle`, and hands it off to `put-line`.

`(gun (relem str))` means repeatedly evaluate the expression `(relem str)` and use the values to generate an lazy sequence, until that expression returns `nil`: ("gun" means "generate until nil"). Since `relem` doesn't return `nil`, we get an infinite sequence of random choices of letters from `str`.  We use `(take n (gun ...))` to just take the first `n`, and then `str-seq` (string from sequence) to turn those letters into a string.

Comment: I really can't get a new random seed, and always get the same "random" password. I tried (defvar *random-state* (make-random-state)) at the top, but it doesn't make a difference...

Comment: @PePa `defvar` does nothing for a variable that already exists; it will not evaluate the expression and will not assign the value to it. `defparm` will do that (and its second argument is mandatory, unlike `defvar`).   `defvar` lets you re-load modules of code without reinitializing their global variables. Since `*random-state*` is already predefined, it makes more sense to just `(set *random-state* (make-random-state))`.